# SSH connection closes immediately after connection is established in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a job in which I establish a SSH connection to a remote server to use `rsync` and copy some files to that server.

I use a managed server where my `SSH` access is only to the root directory of the website.

So the command `~/.ssh` points to the root of the website. But that's not a problem because this is considered my home folder.

The problem is that the connection is established successfully but immediately after that, in the next line, the connection is not available anymore.

```
- ssh -v myssh_user@$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_DEPLOY "whoami && ls"
- whoami
- ls
```

so at the first line the output is :

```
myssh_user    <- means I'm connected and see the right user 
index.php
```

then on the second and third line the output is:

```
gitlab_runner  <- means I'm out of ssh connection again and back to my host 
Dockerfile
DockerfileLocal
app_root
docker
docker-compose-local.yaml
docker-compose.yaml
nginx
```

when I try `rsync` I get permission denied, because obviously the connection is not available:

```
    - rsync -avz $CI_PROJECT_DIR/app_root myssh_user@site.com:/directory/to/copy/the/files
```

this is the last section of the log output of the `gitlab CI/CD` job:

```
ssh -v myssh_user@$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_DEPLOY "whoami && ls"
myssh_user
index.php
$ whoami
gitlab-runner
$ ls
Dockerfile
DockerfileLocal
app_root
docker
docker-compose-local.yaml
docker-compose.yaml
nginx
...
...
...
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2276, received 3088 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3933.4, received 5336.7
debug1: Exit status 0
$ rsync -avz $CI_PROJECT_DIR/app_root ssh-328350-bdb@$website.com:/directory/to/copy/the/files
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh-328350-bdb@website.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

As you see, my `SSH` connection is only available directly on the same line where I actually connect and then it's closed automatically for some reason.

Can anybody tell me how to keep it open?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ssh user@host "command"` then the client will:

1. Connect to the specified remote host
2. Run the specified command(s) on the remote host
3. Disconnect after the last command

That's intentional, and it can be pretty useful IMHO.

If you want to execute the rsync command on the remote host, then you'll need to run that command from within an SSH session - something like `ssh user@host "rsync -avz $CI_PROJECT_DIR/app_root myssh_user@site.com:/directory/to/copy/the/files"`, or tacked onto the end of the existing SSH command, or as part of a script on that remote host that does all the things.